# How to use multiple subject filter in Azur logic app for office 365

Tags: azure, filter, automation, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have been Implementing a logic app which trigger when a email come from specific email id then it perform some task.

I have inserted a subject line filer (I want to select multiple subject filter) but comma',' its not working here to separate different subject line.

Example I want to trigger logic app once email come from xxxx@gmail.com and subject line should be **REST** OR **BEST** or **FAKE** apart from these any subject line logic app should not trigger.

I tried below method but its not working

[image]

Please help me to implement same, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we cannot add multiple filter conditions in the same `Subject Filter` line.

I think its principle should be to determine whether the `Subject` contains the string you specify. For example, the method you mentioned should be to determine whether the email `Subject` contains the string `REST,BEST,FAKE`.

The solution I can think of is to create multiple `Azure Logic App`, and then specify `Subject Filter` as `REST`, `BEST` and `FAKE` respectively.

========================update======================

You can click `Add new parameter` and select `Include Attachments`, then set it to `Yes`:

[image]

You can select `Attachment Size` in the dynamic content, and then use the [condition statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement#add-condition) to compare whether the size meets the set value. Then send the mail in `True` branch:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Can I get Email attachment size in logic app and put some email alert if file size is below set limit ?

Comment: @aamirmalik127. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks ,I will try it and will ask you if face any difficulties.